# EXISTS Condition in MySQL does not work

Tags: mysql, exists

Query as below does not work:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INDIVIDUAL WHERE INDIVIDUAL_ID=1);
```

But it works if

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INDIVIDUAL WHERE INDIVIDUAL_ID=1);
```

I want to run this query not only for MySQL, so is there any way to run without DUAL table?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't `SELECT` without `FROM`

Comment: @d_ominic: SELECT works in redshift without FROM in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is not possible in mysql but you can achieve by below query-

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(INDIVIDUAL_ID)>0,NULL,1) 
FROM INDIVIDUAL 
WHERE INDIVIDUAL_ID=1;
```

If you share your exact requirement then can be change accordingly.